# Javascript \ change double byte Japanese space to an English space

Tags: javascript, string, internationalization

I have a text box to enter text, but the server can't handle double byte space.
I'd like to convert it to regular space before sending.

Tried to do

```
var content = "よろしいでしょう　キャンセル"
content = content.replace("　", " ");
```

but now IDE is screaming that it can't save it that way.
is there standard way to do it?

The request header from Fiddler:

```
POST /blablabla/SearchTerm HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 290
Accept: application/json
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost/blablabla
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

and the request itself is from fiddler:

```
{...."content":"\u3088\u308d\u3057\u3044\u3067\u3057\u3087\u3046\u3000\u30ad\u30e3\u30f3\u30bb\u30eb"....}
```

and the Ajax call from javascript

```
  // Invoke request to server and register to the success and failure events
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: '/blablabla/SearchTerm',
                method: "POST",
                headers: this.header || {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                },
                jsonData: {                  
                    content: content,                   
                },
                timeout: this.configuration.getAjaxRequestTimeout(),
                success: searchCompletedSuccessDelegate,
                failure: searchCompletedFailureDelegate
            });
```

Comment: What are your file encoding, server encoding (in Content-type header) and what is your IDE please?

Comment: in fiddler I see Content-Type: application/json, IDE is VS2012

Comment: Ok fore the IDE. We also need to know what your encoding is: UTF-8 or another one (UTF-x, ISO-xxx etc..) the Content-Type you give doesn't specify it.

Comment: will get that tomorrow ;)

Comment: I added the request header to question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your IDE doesn't support the encoding of the space \u3000 , so you can use unicode notation with \u escape (don't know the real name):

```
//will work in any case
var content = "\u3088\u308d\u3057\u3044\u3067\u3057\u3087\u3046\u3000\u30ad\u30e3\u30f3\u30bb\u30eb";
content.replace("\u3000"," ")
```

I don't know for VS, but some IDE can configure the file to be encoded into UTF-8 to avoid that problem.